# I want to find the sum of the counts of tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

Please find below the Query i use

```
select cm.city_name,

count(case when k.listing_status_uid=1 then 1 end ) as 'Active',   
count(case when k.listing_status_uid=3 then 1 end ) as 'Bad_listing',  
count(case when k.listing_status_uid=4 then 1 end ) as 'proj_scrapped',  
count(case when k.listing_status_uid=5 then 1 end ) as 'proj_on_hold',  
count(case when k.listing_status_uid=6 then 1 end ) as 'sold_out',  
count(case when k.listing_status_uid=7 then 1 end ) as 'others'

from ksl_listing_master k  
join ksl_locality_master lm on lm.locality_uid=k.listing_locality  
join ksl_city_master cm on cm.city_uid=lm.city_uid  
join ksl_listing_status ls on ls.listing_status_uid=k.listing_status_uid  

group by cm.city_name
```

This gives an output like the below one

[image: The image shows the output which i get when i execute the above query]

Now I want the sum of each individual column.
Below the city names Sum should be there
I want the individual sum of `Active`, `Bad_listing`, `proj_scrapped`, `proj_on_hold`, `sold_out`, and `others` in the same Query.

Comment: Come on, you know how to provide a fiddle by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a summary row.  You can do this using `with rollup`:

```
select . . .
group by cm.city_name with rollup;
```

Comment: holy cow! I've been doing this in code after the query for years.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select cm.city_name,
       sum(k.listing_status_uid = 1) as 'Active',   
       sum(k.listing_status_uid = 3) as 'Bad_listing',  
       sum(k.listing_status_uid = 4) as 'proj_scrapped',  
       . . .
       sum(k.listing_status_uid in (1,3,4)) as 'total'
from ksl_listing_master k join 
     ksl_locality_master lm 
     on lm.locality_uid = k.listing_locality join 
     ksl_city_master cm 
     on cm.city_uid=lm.city_uid join 
     ksl_listing_status ls 
     on ls.listing_status_uid = k.listing_status_uid  
group by cm.city_name;
```

Comment: with the sum function iam again getting the count .But i want the sum of the count as shown in the image